# Angular4 Ability to check for previous route

Tags: angular, redirect, angular2-routing, angular4-router

I am trying to control the flow of components - some components cannot be accessed directly i.e must come from a previous component.
e.g OrderDetails component must be completed and validated before you can access Payment component.

Can't stop a user entering "localhost:xxxxx/#/PaymentDetails"

How can I check the user has come from the OrderDetails component and has completed the form?
I have tried below in the PaymentDetails component but doesn't work.

Any help guidance highly appreciated.

```
this.router.events
.filter(e => e instanceof RoutesRecognized)
.pairwise()
.subscribe((event: any[]) => {
            console.log(event[0].urlAfterRedirects);
            console.log(event[0]);
            alert("PREVIOUS" +event[0].urlAfterRedirects);

 });

 this.router.events
 .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
 .pairwise()
 .subscribe((value: [NavigationEnd, NavigationEnd]) => {
            let previousUrl = value[0].url;
            let nextUrl = value[1].url;
            console.log(value);
            alert("PR" + previousUrl);
            alert("CR" + nextUrl);
        });
```

Comment: What's the point of having a route to a component that you can't go to? Why couldn't you see a payment detail weeks after you've made the payment, without filling out an order form? And if PaymentDetails is simply a step of some ordering wizard, then you can use a guard: https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication

Comment: thanks - that really helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CanActivate Routeguard to handle valid Routing to your PaymentDetailComponent. The components can communicate via a service and this service holds a state which has to be true to succesfully route to PaymentDetailsComponent.

For more details check the angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication)

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router }    from '@angular/router';
import { OrderDetailService } from './path/to/OrderDetailService';


@Injectable()
export class PaymentDetailsGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private ods: OrderDetailService,
              private router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    // Check here if OrderDetailService holds valid data, e.g valid form 
    // otherwise navigate the user to your OrderDetailComponent
    if (this.ods.validToProceedToPaymentDetails) {
      return true
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/orderDetail'])
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option.
In PaymentComponent, create an Input field, and inject a Router

```
@Input('ok') private _ok: string

//------------------------------------------------------------//

constructor(private _router: Router) {
     super();

 }//ctor

//------------------------------------------------------------//

ngOnInit() {
  if (!this._ok)
    this._router.navigate(['/home'])
}//ngOnInit
```

In order-details.html do this.

```
<app-payment *ngIf="_goToPayment"  [ok]="'ok'"></app-payment>
```

If PaymentComponent is accessed any other way than from OrderDetailsComponent then the field

```
this._ok==undefined
```